# obfuscating SPA (Single-Page-Application) binaries and .dll files to secure startup.cs and context.cs classes

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application, obfuscation, decompiler, confuserex

I have developed a SPA (single-page-application) using react and Asp.net core and published to a folder as a self-contained App which will be deployed on the client desktop computer and work as desktop app.
I want to obfuscate the `binaries` and `.dll` files of published folder using `neo-confuserex` so that the user may not decompile the app to see `startup.cs`,`context.cs` and `controller.cs` classes.
the screenshot of the folder structure of the published folder is  attached here.

[image: first screenshot here]
here is second
[image: second here]
as there is a long list of files so the last screenshot is here
[image: last]
**my question is to identify the files which should be obfuscated and leave the extra remaining files which are necessary to run the app on desktop computer.**